# C# Generic .Contains() method implementing SqlFunctions.StringConvert in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda, generic-method

I have a generic method which dynamically creates a query in Entity Framework.
I use this as a search function on data table headers.

The function works perfectly if the Entity property type/SQL data type is a string. This is because of the .Contains() extensions.

The problem comes in when the data type is something other than a string.
These data types don't have the .Contains() extension.

I would like to be able to use this method across all data types, and have found that I could possibly use SqlFunctions.StringConvert. I also know that it has no option for integer, and will have to convert the integer based properties into double.

I am unsure how to implement SqlFunctions.StringConvert generically, please see my below method (you will see that I have excluded the data types which have no .Contains() extension):

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<SearchFilterDto> filters)
        where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0 && !filters.Any(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Filter)))
        {
            Expression filterExpression = null;

            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item");

            filterExpression = filters.Select(f =>
            {
                Expression selector = parameter;
                Expression pred = Expression.Constant(f.Filter);

                foreach (var member in f.Column.Split('.'))
                {
                    PropertyInfo mi = selector.Type.GetProperty(member, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (mi != null)
                    {
                        selector = Expression.Property(selector, mi);

                        if (selector.Type == typeof(Guid) ||
                        selector.Type == typeof(Guid?) ||
                        selector.Type == typeof(DateTime) ||
                        selector.Type == typeof(DateTime?) ||   
                        selector.Type == typeof(int) ||
                        selector.Type == typeof(int?)

                            )
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                Expression containsMethod = Expression.Call(selector, "Contains", null, pred);

                return containsMethod;
            }).Where(r => r != null).Aggregate(Expression.And);
            LambdaExpression where = Expression.Lambda(filterExpression, parameter);
            MethodInfo whereCall = (typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == "Where" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(query.ElementType));
            MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(whereCall, new Expression[] { query.Expression, where });
            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function works perfectly if the Entity property type/SQL data type is a string. This is because of the .Contains() extensions.

I would like to mention that the `Contains` in this case is not an extension, but a regular `string.Contains` method.

> I would like to be able to use this method across all data types

This is not a good idea since the non string values can have different string representations, so it's not quite clear what you'll be searching for.

But let assume you want it anyway.

> and have found that I could possibly use SqlFunctions.StringConvert

There are two drawbacks - first, `SqlFunctions` are SqlServer specific (not like `DbFunctions` for instance), and second, `StringConvert` works only with `double` and `decimal`. IMO the better choice would be using the `object.ToString` method which is supported in EF (at least in the lastest EF6).

I'm going to provide you a solution based on `object.ToString()`. But before doing that, let me give you some hints when working with expressions. Anytime you want to build an expression using `System.Linq.Expressions` and don't know how, you can build a similar sample typed expression and examine it inside the debugger Locals/Watch window. For instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> e = item =>
    SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)item.Bar).Contains("1");
```

You can put a break point and start expanding `e` members, then their members etc. and you'll see how the expression has been built by the compiler, then all you need is to find the respective `Expression` methods.

Finally, here is the solution itself. I've also included some little tricks that allow avoiding working directly with reflection and string method names where possible:

```
public static class QueryableUtils
{
    static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Expr<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> source) { return source; }

    static MethodInfo GetMethod(this LambdaExpression source) { return ((MethodCallExpression)source.Body).Method; }

    static readonly MethodInfo Object_ToString = Expr((object x) => x.ToString()).GetMethod();

    static readonly MethodInfo String_Contains = Expr((string x) => x.Contains("y")).GetMethod();

    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<SearchFilterDto> filters)
        // where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0 && !filters.Any(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Filter)))
        {
            var item = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item");
            var body = filters.Select(f =>
            {
                // Process the member path and build the final value selector
                Expression value = item;
                foreach (var memberName in f.Column.Split('.'))
                {
                    var member = item.Type.GetProperty(memberName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ??
                        (MemberInfo)item.Type.GetField(memberName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (member == null) return null; // Should probably throw an error?
                    value = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(value, member);
                }
                // NOTE: "Safe" skipping invalid arguments is not a good practice.
                // Without that requirement, the above block will be simply
                // var value = f.Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)item, Expression.PropertyOrField);
                // Convert value to string if needed
                if (value.Type != typeof(string))
                {
                    // Here you can use different conversions based on the value.Type
                    // I'll just use object.ToString()
                    value = Expression.Call(value, Object_ToString);
                }
                // Finally build and return a call to string.Contains method
                return (Expression)Expression.Call(value, String_Contains, Expression.Constant(f.Filter));
            })
            .Where(r => r != null)
            .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
            query = query.Where(predicate);
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for the great explanation and examples!

Comment: Is is possible to make an exception for the DateTime type? EF is producing " CAST(DateAS nvarchar(max)) " which gives some horrible date-format (which no ones seems to know how to change). The correct conversion method for SQL is apparently CONVERT(), which would take an extra param for the date-format.

Comment: @SeanThorburn Yeah, that was one of the concerns. Unfortunately as you already know, the only supported conversions to string are 'object.ToString()` (no format args) and `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` for numeric (again no format options). Eventually you may try composing something using date parts and string concatenation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384930/c-sharp-generic-datetime-tostring-with-custom-format/