# SQL Server Date CAST default format

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Where does SQL Server get the default date format it uses when returning results from:

```
CAST(LastLogin AS nvarchar(max))
```

I would like to change this default format. I cannot use CONVERT() because this query is being generated by Entity Framework.

I am getting:

```
Jun 22 2015  4:02PM
Jul 19 2015 10:02PM
Jan 30 2016  3:45PM
Jan 18 2016  2:56PM
Feb  4 2016 12:27PM
May  7 2015  9:30AM
etc.
```

I have looked at the regional settings on the server and it has not been set to use this date format.

If interested in the EF issue: [C# Generic .Contains() method implementing SqlFunctions.StringConvert in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243655/c-sharp-generic-contains-method-implementing-sqlfunctions-stringconvert-in-en/35273158#35273158)

Comment: Why are you converting to a string anyways if you're using EF? Why not just do that on the client side?

Comment: Can't you tell entity framework to return the value as a `DateTime`? Then you can format the date as you wish using .NET formatting options.

Comment: Don't use sql-server, but most DBMS platforms have some kind of FORMAT function, where you can specify the format to use to translate date/time fields to a string.

Comment: And where are you seeing that format?  In SQL or in .NET?

Comment: @DStanley SET DateFormat has no affect on the CAST result. I am getting this result in SQL.

Comment: @Heinzi, Sure, but that's another problem. This question is MSSQL based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to change this default format.

Simply put: **You can't.**

```
CAST(LastLogin AS nvarchar(max))
```

is equivalent to

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), LastLogin)
```

is equivalent to

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), LastLogin, 0)
```

which [is specified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to return the following format:

```
mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)
```

*(As other have already noted, this is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661), and you might want to start a question on the real problem you are facing.)*

Answer (score 4):

I think one good way is to try to tackle the underlying problem that caused the `CAST` to be generated. It is better to retrieve `DATE/DATETIME/DATETIME2` value into `C# DateTime` properties and then [apply the formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) based on needed format/culture.

**[later edit]**
I think the default string representation of a time depends on both instance language and its default date representation. First can be seen in instance properties:

[image]

The second is specified in `CAST/CONVERT` documentation:

> Default for datetime and smalldatetime - mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)

Both language and datetime format for a session can be changed using [SET LANGUAGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) and/or [SET DATEFORMAT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx), but the later seems to affect only how `datetime`s are parsed, not how CAST displays the formatted date.

Comment: Thanks Alexi, that will be the next step. This question is simply - Where is SQL server getting this default Date format from.