# C# Generic DateTime.ToString() with custom format

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda, generic-method

When using:

```
DateTime.ToString().Contains("2016")
```

Entity Framework produces:

```
CAST(DateValue AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%2016%'
```

This uses the default date-format "mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)"

I would like to user "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)" which is obtainable with something like:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), DateValue, 20) LIKE '%2016%'
```

I need help implementing this format to an existing generic method.

```
static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Expr<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> source) { return source; }
static MethodInfo GetMethod(this LambdaExpression source) { return ((MethodCallExpression)source.Body).Method; }
static readonly MethodInfo Object_ToString = Expr((object x) => x.ToString()).GetMethod();
static readonly MethodInfo String_Contains = Expr((string x) => x.Contains("y")).GetMethod();

public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<SearchFilterDto> filters)
 where T : BaseEntity
{
    if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0 && !filters.Any(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Filter)))
    {
        var item = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item");
        var body = filters.Select(f =>
        {
            var value = f.Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)item, Expression.PropertyOrField);
            if (value.Type != typeof(string))
            {
                value = Expression.Call(value, Object_ToString);
            }

            return (Expression)Expression.Call(value, String_Contains, Expression.Constant(f.Filter));
        })
        .Where(r => r != null)
        .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda(body, item);
        MethodInfo whereCall = (typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == "Where" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(query.ElementType));
        MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(whereCall, new Expression[] { query.Expression, predicate });
        query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Please note, this is an example - it will not always be "2016" and not always be a year. The user may type the time, or "01" to recall all records either on the 1st day of the month, January or in 2001. It's a very flexible filter.

I also understand that many people will not like this situation, but I am really looking for a solution here and not be told "don't do this"

The solution also needs to cater for LINQ to Entities, so I cant simply .ToString("MMM d yyyy H:mm tt") as this will result in:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

The code works with the default date-format. The reason for my question is to change the date-format at SQL level, by manipulating the query in Entity Framework.

Comment: I don't think using LIKE with dates is such a good idea. You could probably get a more efficient query by not converting the date into a string. What is it that you are actually trying to achieve, i.e. what would you use in place of "xyz" in practice?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, I have replaced xyz with a better example - 2016. The text is coming from an open text box. If you have a better way of working with dates, I'm all for it! It just needs to be flexible and accurate no matter what the string/filter contains.

Comment: You should not mix code and data like that. You probably should parse text field into integer (to get year). SQL has DATEPART function, probably EF will translate DateTime.Year == value to DATEPART.

Comment: @OlehNechytailo, I have added more text to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to produce the desired result is manually building it with expression like this

```
Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> Date_ToString = date =>
    DbFunctions.Right("000" + date.Year.ToString(), 4) + "-" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Month.ToString(), 2) + "-" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Day.ToString(), 2) + " " +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Hour.ToString(), 2) + ":" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Minute.ToString(), 2) + ":" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Second.ToString(), 2);
```

Ugly, I know. And frankly you don't want to see the EF generated SQL from the above expression - a huge monster compared to the desired `CONVERT(...)`. But at least it works.

Here is the code. One could build the above expression using `System.Linq.Expressions`, but I'm too lazy for that and used a simple parameter replacer.

The modified part:

```
if (value.Type != typeof(string))
{
    if (value.Type == typeof(DateTime))
        value = value.ToDateString();
    else if (value.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
        value = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.NotEqual(value, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?))),
            Expression.Property(value, "Value").ToDateString(),
            Expression.Constant(""));
    else
        value = Expression.Call(value, Object_ToString);
}
```

and the used helpers:

```
static readonly Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> Date_ToString = date =>
    DbFunctions.Right("000" + date.Year.ToString(), 4) + "-" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Month.ToString(), 2) + "-" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Day.ToString(), 2) + " " +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Hour.ToString(), 2) + ":" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Minute.ToString(), 2) + ":" +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + date.Second.ToString(), 2);

static Expression ToDateString(this Expression source)
{
    return Date_ToString.ReplaceParameter(source);
}

static Expression ReplaceParameter(this LambdaExpression expression, Expression target)
{
    return new ParameterReplacer { Source = expression.Parameters[0], Target = target }.Visit(expression.Body);
}

class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression Source;
    public Expression Target;
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I was half way with a monster datepart-concat abomination when I reached a SQL "nested to level 10" exception. 
I need to go through this code in detail, I will learn a lot from it. 
Thank you for your time and effort, I am extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine if the date is within the year from your input value why not:

`DateTime.Year == 2016 //or your variable`

Maybe there is more to your need than I am seeing, though.

Comment: Please see updated question. I have added text explaining why this will not help.

Comment: How will you know if what is being passed is a month, day, or year?

Comment: You don't, and don't need to. The code works with the default date-format. The reason for my question is to change the date-format at the SQL level by manipulating the query in Entity Framework.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but if you get a value of 15, which was meant as the date number - wouldn't a 2015 date match always (based on the pattern match)? If so, that doesn't seem like a very accurate and consistent way to handle this. Again, correct me if I am misunderstanding something here with your program.

Comment: You are correct, it should match - and so then the user must be more specific with the value - to limit the filtered results.

Comment: So you are basically allowing the user to provide a pattern to match on the date?

Comment: Yes, in the form of an empty text box. if they type something stupid or non-specific - they are not going to get good results.

Comment: Gotcha. Based on this: 'I would like to user "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)"', the user could match on hours, minutes, and seconds. If that is the intended affect (bad user experience?) then it sounds like you need to use regular expressions.

Comment: You are correct, I will obviously adjust it if users complain about the filtering - but for now I would like to include everything. Give it a try with regular expressions, see if you can solve it :)

Comment: With all due respect, this is not my challenge - it is yours. I could certainly "give it a try", but shouldn't you? I'm not here to do your work for you - just to help point you into the direction of a possible solution.

Comment: Sure, but I have no cooking clue how you are going to use regular expressions to manipulate the SQL generated by Entity Framework to use the CONVERT function over CAST, so I'm all-eyes on a basic example :)